# Submitting to App Store, App downloads >500Byte file for the first few times

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

I have a little question, I have just started my way developing, newly to this, have already submitted some little with Nokia but am very excited about apple app store, I'm cocos2d to help me with it, to the point,

My app downloads a text file that is under 500Bytes in size around 3 times in it's life, in It's life I mean that's it, even if you close your app, it's done with it.

The second thing is when you click a special faceboo, twitter button, it downloads a text that is also very small in size, and use it as an input text to share it on facebook or twitter,

That's all without the knowledge of the user, but if it's not connected to the internet, it will not interpret the user and will take the last version it have.

Although in some places of my app, I warn my user if there's no internet, but not in the facebook button.

Hope I delivered my question clear enough, thank you !

Comment: Uh... what is the question? Are you asking if it is OK to download a little file? Sure it is. But why not just include this text file in the app bundle, if it's so small? (If you are trying to provide a way for your app to always have the latest version of the file, then downloading it makes some sense.)

Comment: Yes, That's the point, once the app is submitted to the app store, I will take the link for it, and use it in my text file. But I hope apple will not refuse my app for that, anyways thanks for your respond. I hope someone will also confirm it.

Comment: i agree with Mark, don't worry!!! 500 bytes is NOTHING to worry about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app can download files, and can request XML or JSON.
You don't have to inform users about download or request process.

These actions are not reasons for being rejected by AppStore.

Comment: Thank you :) hope my app will pass it from the first time.